# histfit Matlab with overlapped Gaussian

Tags: matlab

I have a distribution which is combined of two overlapped Gaussians and I'd like to fit Gaussians to its histogram. I know that histfit in Matlab does it perfectly but for 1 gaussian. and also histfit(data,bin,dist) does for other type of distribution provided by default but two-normal is not included there.

How can I do this two-normal fitting by histfit?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, use gmdistribution instead.

E.g.
obj = gmdistribution.fit(data, 2)

will estimate parameters of two gaussians in the gaussian mixture distribution.

Comment: Thanks, so i dont waste time on that option! 

now the question is that when I use this command, I get something like:


obj =

Gaussian mixture distribution with 2 components in 1 dimensions Component 1: Mixing proportion: 0.499387 Mean: -0.4789

Component 2: Mixing proportion: 0.500613 Mean: -0.4786

Now, how can I plot this together with the original histogram? 

I am aware of these 2 links but they dont help me so much:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/317868

http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/stats/gmdistribution.fit.html

Any clear help is highly appreciated!